# Questions about books that are helpful in practicing for math olympiads!

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I would like you to tell me some books that are very good for math practicing for senior olympiads ( one or two for geometry, one or two books for number theory... or books for every of these) . Also I want to know what you think about these books:

Problems and Solutions in Euclidean Geometry
By: M. N. Aref, William Wernick

Challenging Problems in Geometry 
by Alfred S. Posamentier  (Author), Charles T. Salkind (Author)

Challenging Problems in Algebra 
By: Alfred S. Posamentier, Charles T. Salkind

Combinatorial Geometry in the Plane
By: Victor Klee, Hugo Hadwiger, Hans Debrunner

One Hundred Problems in Elementary Mathematics
By: Hugo Steinhaus, Martin Gardner

100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics
By: Heinrich Dörrie

Thank you very much ! And please tell me the best books I can find on Dover or Amazon !

Comment: How can I find that?

Comment: Good on you for preparing for math Olympiad.